# How to stretch SVGs with an expanding parent container?

Tags: css, svg

I have a div that holds two inline SVGs. When the user mouses over that div, I use a CSS transformation to double its height. I'd like the SVGs' height to scale with the parent div as it changes.

Currently, when I mouseover the parent div, its height changes properly, as does the SVGs' height, but when I mouseout, their height shrinks immediately drops down to its original value, [like this](http://www.dcwebdev.net/timecapsule/svg-scale-test.htm).

HTML:

```
<div id="nav">
    <div id="logo">Time Capsule</div>
    <div id="navButtons">
        <a href="#" id="loginBttn">
            <svg height="100%" viewBox="0 0 50 50" id="loginSVG">
                <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="25" stroke="none" fill="blue" class="background" />
                <polyline points="15,10, 35,10, 35,40, 15,40" style="stroke:white; stroke-width:4; fill:none" class="door"/>
                <g id="arrow">
                    <line x1="25" y1="25" x2="10" y2="25" style="stroke:white; stroke-width:4" class="arrowSpine"/>
                    <polyline points="15,20,10,25,15,30" style="stroke:white; stroke-width:4; fill:none" class="arrowPoint" />
                </g>
            </svg>
        </a>
        <a href="register.php">
            <svg height="100%" viewBox="0 0 50 50" id="loginSVG">
                <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="25" stroke="none" fill="blue" class="background" />
                <line x1="10" x2="40" y1="25" y2="25" style="stroke:white; stroke-width:4" />
                <line x1="25" x2="25" y1="10" y2="40" style="stroke:white; stroke-width:4" />
            </svg>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#nav { background-color:#000; width:100%; height:50px; transition:height 0.5s; }
#nav svg { height:50px; width:50px; }
#nav:hover { height:100px; transition:height 0.5s; }
#nav:hover svg { height:100px; width:100px; transition:height 0.5s; }
#nav:hover svg .background { height:100px; width:100px; transition: height 0.5s; }
#nav #logo { color:white; float:left; }
#nav #navButtons { float:right; top:-20px; }
```

Is there a way to fix the mouseover behavior with just css? I know I could use javascript, but I'm curious if a css-only fix is possible.

Comment: Please create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @PaulLeBeau, I changed the link to point to an MCVE.

Comment: You need to put the transition on the svg not just the hover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the transition property to the base class instead (not the pseudo class :hover) and add the width property in the transition as well.

```
#nav svg {
   transition:height 0.5s, width 0.5s;
}
```

The problem with your current code is that the transition only happens when the mouse *hovers* the element. If you want to scale with an animation back to the original state, the transition css property needs to be active even when the hover is not in effect.

Comment: I made the change you suggested, but I'm still having the same issue.

Comment: @zzxjoanw: Fixed it for you

Comment: @zzxjoanw Did the current answer work for you or did you experience any other problems?

Comment: I added the width transition, but I'm still having the same issue. I tested it in Firefox 44 and Chrome 48.

Comment: That's weird, it works when I try it. Try adding the browser specific transition  properties perhaps. You are interested in the animation minimizing the svg image when you don't hover the image, right?

Comment: btw, I looked at your page now and you've entered the property wrong. You typed `width:0.5s`, but it should be as I wrote it in the answer, with no `:`.

Comment: Don't forget to remove the transition from the :hover state as well, otherwise that might interfere with the animation when you hover the svg image.

Comment: Thanks, @Patrick, it's working now! Can't believe I missed that colon.